# "A Bluetooth audio error occurred"

Tags: macos, mac, bluetooth

I'm getting this popping up on my Mac multiple times a day:

[image]

I have an Apple keyboard attached via Bluetooth, and nothing else. It doesn't say anything else is connected either, just this alert pops up every so often.

Answer (score 2):

Disable external requests by checking the Reject incoming Audio requests!

Also check your BT settings to make sure you do not have Audio devices set up.

It is possible you get the error from there.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that, I've unchecked both those checkboxes and problem still occurs.

Comment: OK, since you blocked incoming requests, and have nothing else set up in bluetooth,, Reset and reinstall Apple keyboard.